# How to I save a list group in SQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, list

I have code in html that adds data in a list by selecting the data in the combo box and clicking on the add button. I am encountering an error "undefined index: subjectlist" when submitting the form. Appreciate your advise this? Thank you. I am still an newbie in web programming.

```
  <h4>Subjects</h4>
  <ul class="list-group list" id='subjectlist' name='subjectlist' >
  </ul>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
  </div>

</form>

<button class="add_field_button" onclick="getsubject()">Add Subject</button>
<button class="add_field_button" onclick="removesubject()">Remove Subject</button>

<script>

  function getsubject(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("subjectlist");
    var candidate = document.getElementById("st");
    var SelectedValue = candidate.options[candidate.selectedIndex].text;
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    li.setAttribute('class',"list-group-item");
    li.setAttribute('id',"subjectlistitem");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SelectedValue));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
</script>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
   $sectioncode = $_POST['sc'];
   $sectiongroup = $_POST['ccg'];
   $selectedsubject = $_POST['st'];
   $subjectlist = $_POST['subjectlist'];
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($subjectlist as $qst) {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO sectionsubject(sectioncode, subjectcoden) VALUES ('" . $csectioncode . "', 
     '" . $subjectlist[$i] . "')";
    if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "success";
    } else {echo "error" . $link->error;}
    $i++;}
 }
?>
```

Comment: `li` elements aren't submitted as form fields. Only `input`, `select`, and `textarea`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Can you advise on any workaround on this? thankyou.

Comment: Use a multi-select input rather than copying the selected values into a list.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, will use multi-select input instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because $_POST,$_GET only deal with `<input>`  tags and `<ul>`,`<li>` are not input methods.